# IntelliJ with Ruby on Rails plugin gives warnings about "not able to find route path" when coding tests using built in mini-test framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, autocomplete, rubymine, minitest

I am new to web dev and Ruby on Rails.  I chose IntelliJ(13.1.5) with ruby plugins since I also have worked with Java apps for many years for saving a lot of typing.  I am trying out rails built-in mini-test framework these days and I have trouble using auto-completion feature for route paths and urls in test classes.  There are many warnings about "Cannot find xxx_path' for my sample code below though the tests do run fine.

```
    get login_path
```

I understand it could be hard for IDE to work with a framework in dynamic language with built in magic.  However, I experimented with RSpec test framework for rails and did not have such problem finding the route definitions in IDE.  I like mini-test's simplicity more, but if IDE could not allow me to work efficiently, I have to think about RSpec again. Not sure if I miss something here or IDE's miss.  Is there anyone else have the same problem with intelliJ mini-test classes for route definition?  Do you get it work properly in Intellij or RubyMine?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Posted it in JetBrains community and was told that this is supposed to be supported.  Filed an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15920

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, it is hard for Intellij to do the magic for dynamic language, it can't be sure about which one you are referencing. I noticed similar issue while writing ruby with IntelliJ IDEA. I'd suggest switching to RubyMine, which is basically a light-weight IntelliJ IDEA but has everything ruby needs. This solved some of my issues, meaning it can find the correct reference when you find declaration, although auto-completion still doesn't work well with instances outside of the current class.

Comment: I use IntelliJ also extensively for my Java work. RubyMine requires separate license.